# How to connect public port 80 to VM port 8080 in windows azure

Tags: node.js, azure, windows-server-2012

I have node.js application that is listening to port 8080 on Azure VM (I use windows server 2012). The application is running well on VM localhost but it still cannot be accessed publicly. I have set up endpoints public 80 and private 8080 but it does not work. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the firewall on the windows server to allow inbound connections on port 8080?

Comment: I have added inbound rules to firewall but it still does not work

Comment: Two tests I routinely run are to try to connect to the service from another VM in the same cloud service, and to temporarily shut down the firewall entirely. This usually helps rule out issues with the endpoint configuration and the firewall.